# binding to a list of tuples

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, tuples

I have a list of tuples pairing two pieces of data... I'd like to bind the list to a data grid.  For display, it works fine... but if I try and modify an entry, it says "A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Item1'"... presumably Tuples are immutable in .NET 4.0.  Is there an easy way to bind to pairs of data without creating a mutable tuple class of my own?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, tuples are immutable.  Anonymous types are also immutable. You should use your own generic type:

```
public class Pair<T, U> 
{
     public Pair() {
     }

     public Pair(T first, U second) {
       this.First = first;
       this.Second = second;
     }

     public T First { get; set; }
     public U Second { get; set; }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error with KeyValuePair type also.